# ./mv.sh: line 4: cd: 1.4-1.5.csh: Not a directory

Tags: linux, bash

I want to move file1 to directory1 in many subdirectories of current directory. Both file1 and directory1 are in each subdirectory. I write the following script in current directory but it reports "./mv.sh: line 4: cd: directory1: No such file or directory". Actually, the directory1 is in each subdirectory.

```
1 #!/bin/bash
2
3 for i in *; do
4    builtin cd $i
5    mv file1 directory1
6    builtin cd ..
7 done
```

error

```
./mv.sh: line 4: cd: directory1: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `file1': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you sure there is `directory1` and `file1` in *all* subdirectories?

Comment: I'm 100% sure. I figure this out!!!there is file(not directory)between those subdirectories. I just delete that file and then that mv.sh script works!!! Does that mean there should be no file between those directories?

Comment: if there is a file between those subdirs. The cd ..will drag me into the higher dirctory. Thanks, guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that `directory1` is a dangling symbolic link? For example:

```
mkdir foo
ln -s foo foolink
mv foo bar # foolink still points to foo but foo is gone!
cd foolink
# bash: cd: foolink: No such file or directory
```

Also, instead of

```
cd dir
mv foo subdir
cd ..
```

I would recommend the more succinct, and more importantly, **safer** version:

```
mv dir/foo dir/subdir/
```

Why is this safer? Imagine that `dir` doesn't exist:

```
cd dir        # Fails
mv foo subdir # Oops! Now we're trying to move a file from the current directory
cd ..         # Even bigger oops! Now we're even higher in the directory tree,
              #   and on the next iteration will be moving files around that we
              #   shouldn't be
```

(You could also avert this issue in this particular case by using `set -o errexit` but in general `cd ..` in scripts is dangerous, in my opinion.)

Also, as Ansgar Wiechers said, you should use `find` instead of trying to crawl the tree yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `find` rather than trying to crawl the directory tree:

```
find . -type f -name "file1" -execdir mv {} directory1/ \;
```

This assumes that each directory with a file `file1` has a subdirectory `directory1`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the `cd ..` in line 6 lead you to another directory. You can check this by inserting `builtin pwd` between lines 6 and 7. This shows you in which directory you actually are after the `cd ..`.

- Maybe one of the directories is in fact a link to another directory? This could be the reason for landing somewhere you did not expect.
- If the `cd $i` fails, you could also land in a wrong directory, this may happen if $i is not a directory or you don't have permission to explore it.

Comment: there is file(not directory)between those subdirectories. I just delete that file and then that mv.sh script works!!!

Comment: if there is a file between those subdirs. The cd ..will drag me into the higher dirctory. Thanks, guys!! cd.. is dangerous.